# Do magnets also attract super conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

If a superconductor can be repelled by a magnet (or, well, locked in a certain position by the magnet) can a magnet be attracted to a superconductor. What would happen if you take a peace of metal, attracted to that powerful magnet, and then cool it to the critical temperature. Would it be repelled or attracted to the magnet (on that side of the magnet)?

Answer (score 0):

The superconductors do repell magnets due to their diamagnetic response and might even lock magnets in certain positions (in case of type II superconductors).

[image]

The superconductor feels the magnetic field of the magnet and reacts to it by behaving like a diamagnet (by creating a field against it and thus expelling it). By turning the poles of the magnet the superconductor will feel the new field and will try to expell the magnetic flux lines once again. The direction of the flux lines would just be in another direction. So it does not matter which side of the magnet you put near the superconductor. It will always be repelled.

Superconductors are usually diamagnets without ferromagnetic properties.  Again, feromagnetic materials (like Fe, Co, Ni) do not exhibit superconducting properties at normal pressure:

[image]

In your case, the piece of metal which is attracted to the magnet has probably ferromagnetic nature. In this case it will normally not be a superconductor and will not change its properties due to the cooling.

If it actually is a superconductor [(has to be a special one](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1006/1006.0065.pdf) [or  another)](http://www.science.uva.nl/research/cmp/docs/deVisser/2010/EMSAT-2010-1.pdf), then it will be repelled underneath the critical temperature. But it is not going to be attracted in this case.

Comment: The repulsive force is due to the expulsion of the magnetic field. Is it relevant whether the superconductor is diamagnetic or ferromagnetic (since there is no field inside it)?

Comment: so wiat will the super conductor be reppeled by the magnet all the time? one it is cooled to the critical tempurature, will flipping the magnet still cause the superconductor to br repelled? Also, can a superconductor be turned into an electromagnet?  (lets say it is a room-temperature super conductor so we can ignore temperature for now.)

Comment: @KeithMcClary In the intermediate superconducting state the field is penetrating through certain regions forming vortices so the field is not completely expelled. In the case of the ferromagnetic superconductor one expects to see ferromagnetic and superconducting phase at the same time probably resulting in less homogeneous behaviour to an external ferromagnet.

Comment: @House It will always be repelled, yes. A superconductor itself is not a magnet, but you can make an electromagnet [electromagnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet) out of it

Comment: What happens if you spin the magnet, will the superconductor stay still or oscillate?

Comment: @Jitter maybe you want to ask this a separate question?

Comment: I THINK IF YOU SPIN IT IT WILL SPIN IN WHATEVER POSITION YOU SPIN IT IN. IT WILL SAY "LOCKED" IN THAT POSITION BECAUSE THATS HOW IT IS "LOCKED IN THE MAGNETIC FIELD. PEOPLE CAN USE THIS PROPERTY DO DISPLAY IT FLOATING IN MUD AIR SO LIKE A SCULPTURE COULD BE DISPLAYED FLOATING IN ANY POSITION YOU PUT IT IN.

Comment: wait but a superconducting electromagnet wouldn't repel a magnet it would attract it right? only repel if it is turned to the other pole.

Comment: cause then it becomes an electr0 magnet with two poles